# Securing eclipse-microprofile metrics and health end points

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

I am using Quarkus to build a REST API.
I have enabled the MicroProfile Health endpoints following https://quarkus.io/guides/microprofile-health

I would like to know how to secure or reduce the visibility of the `<IP>:8080/health` endpoints so that it wont be visible to external users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can then use the below configuration :

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public.paths=/health/*,/metrics/*,/openapi/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public.policy=authenticated
```

If your security is not enabled, then please check this [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security#authenticating-via-http).